# Are there any recent 64-bit VFW screen capture codecs out there?

Tags: after-effects, codec, screen-casting

I'm currently editing some video screen capture recordings I did under Linux using recordMyDesktop (basically OGG Theora video files).

Since there's currently no way to import Theora video into After Effects CC, I first need to transcode the video files into an intermediate format. I first tried with the Huffyuv and Lagarith losless codecs, but the file sizes came up too big.

I also tried transcoding to MP4 using ffmpeg with mixed results. It seems that After effects only likes a particular kind of MP4 encoded videos which I have yet to find. In my case, the footage would show intermittent "video offline" frames, which is undesirable.

The My ideal codec would be something that:

- Uses screen capture specific compression.
- Can be enumerated as a 64bit VFW codec inside Virtualdub 64.
- Runs in 64 bit mode (since I need to decode and edit inside After Effects).
- It's free (I'd pay for one, but first I'd like to exhaust my options).

Finally, I tried looking for VFW compatible screen capture codecs and here's what I found:

- TSCC codec - TechSmith: Not free. Free version does not allow me to encode video using Virtualdub. I think this one can run with 64-bit applications.
- inno Screen Capture Codec(iSCC): Not free. Don't know if runs in 64-bit mode.
- MSU Screen Capture Lossless Codec: Free. Compresses files fairly nice. I think it kind of messes with the framerate of the video. Unfortunately, I didn't find a 64-bit build of the codec, so the 32-bit codec encoded files get rejected by After Effects :(.

I also read about using ffmpeg to encode to Quicktime mov with an animation codec here https://video.stackexchange.com/a/8315/6059. So I'll give that a try.

So has anyone else done something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a 64bit codec to use it in 64bit Software like VirtualDub or After Effects, a 32bit codec will work just fine.
For intermediate codecs I generally use either a QuickTime with `PhotoJPEG` compression or `Animation` like you suggested yourself. The latter is lossless and produces fairly big files, the former is lossy just like JPEG but offers visually lossless compression with a reasonable size and works very well in every software that supports QuickTime video.

Another alternative would be a `JPEG2000` image sequence which can be be either lossless or lossy, though its a bit less fun to work with as you end up with thousands of files in a folder, though there are commercial `JPEG2000` codecs out there that are 64bit native and integrate into Windows.

Another good (open source) alternative is [Ut Video](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Ut-Video-Codec-Suite). It also features a native 64bit version of the codec and integrates into Windows aswell. It's completely lossless but produces files with reasonable size.

Comment: Thank you. I pretty much ended up settling with `ffmpeg` encoding into video frames using the `qtrle` codec and placing them under `.mov` files. In my case generated about 120Mb per minute, which I think is quite suitable since After Effects does understand that video codec.

Comment: Bare in mind that RLE codecs are very inefficent. If you want lossless go with UT video, the compression ratio and decoding performance is a ton better.